# Theory on custom loss functions for GBDT and other ML

Tags: machine-learning, references, loss-functions, boosting

I'm looking for resources on the theory behind choosing a loss function for ML---I'm interested in GBDT but for deep learning would work as well. I'd like to get a better understanding of how the loss function affects the model, the difference between validation loss and training loss, etc.

I've googled around and most medium articles I find are too superficial, and I don't know where to start looking for more academic resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the difference between validation loss and training loss, etc.

This is addressed to some extent in chapter 7 of **Elements of Statistical Learning** which [is available for free from the authors online](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf).

There are some other general discussions of loss function properties in other chapters of that book (Chapter 3, Chapter 4, Chapter 10 for example).

> I'm interested in GBDT

[The original paper on Boosting](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF00116037.pdf) by Schapire might be useful, as well as [this later paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.53.1080&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by the same author.

Some other general papers on loss functions:

[The original paper on L1 regularization by Tibshirani](https://cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/csc2515-2006/readings/lasso.pdf)

[A comparison of L1 and L2 regularization by Andrew Ng](https://icml.cc/Conferences/2004/proceedings/papers/354.pdf)

The original paper on L2 regularization by Tikhonov is in Russian, you might be able to find a translation somewhere.